# Highlight some code lines with asciidoc

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

I'm just learning asciidoc to create my own Documentation. So far I'm using the following markup to highlight source code:

```
[source,xml,subs="verbatim,attributes"]
---- 
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
----
```

I still haven't figured out how to highlight parts of the code.Any help ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess the asciidoctor way is to use [callouts](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#callouts):

```
[source,xml,subs="verbatim,attributes"]
---- 
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.1</version> <!--1-->
</dependency>
---- 
<1> : The version is part of the coordinates
```

This is rendered like this:

[image: Asciidoc listing with callouts]